# Convert MySql Union query to laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to convert this query to Laravel query and i want to add where clause with customer id.
I tried to convert this query into laravel query but is not working for me. It shows error *Unknown column 'null' in 'field list*'. This Query is working on Sql.
.

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT sale_invoice_masters.id,
sale_invoice_masters.customer_id, NULL AS amount, NULL AS recovery_date,
 sale_invoice_masters.grand_total,
 sale_invoice_masters.cash_amount, sale_invoice_masters.credit_amount, 
sale_invoice_masters.sale_date FROM sale_invoice_masters) 

UNION ALL(SELECT recoveries.id ,recoveries.customer_id,
recoveries.amount,  recoveries.recovery_date,
 NULL AS grand_total, NULL AS cash_amount,
NULL AS credit_amount,NULL AS sale_date FROM recoveries))
 results ORDER BY sale_date DESC , recovery_date DESC
```

```
public function getCustomerRecord(Request $request)
    {

        $customers = Customer::where('id', $request->get('customer_id'))->get();
        $customerID = Customer::find($customers);

    $customerCreditSales = SaleInvoiceMaster::select('sale_invoice_masters.id'
            , 'sale_invoice_masters.customer_id',
            'NULL AS amount',
            'NULL AS recovery_date',
            'sale_invoice_masters.grand_total',
            'sale_invoice_masters.cash_amount',
            'sale_invoice_masters.credit_amount',
            'sale_invoice_masters.sale_date');

        $recoveries = Recovery::select(['recoveries.id'
                , 'recoveries.customer_id'
                , 'recoveries.amount',
            'recoveries.recovery_date',
            'NULL AS grand_total',
            'NULL AS cash_amount',
            'NULL AS credit_amount',
            'NULL AS sale_date',
            ])
            ->unionAll($customerCreditSales)->where('customer_id',$request->get('customer_id'))
            ->get();

        $htmlCredit = '';
        foreach ($recoveries as $sales) {

            $htmlCredit .= '<tr id="row_' . $sales->id . '">' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->customer_id . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->sale_date . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->recovery_date . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->total_amount . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->cash_amount . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->credit_amount . '</td > ' .
                '<td > ' . $sales->amount . '</td > ' .
                '</tr> ';
        }

        $result = array('name' => $customerID[0]->name, 'contact' => $customerID[0]->contact,
            'city' => $customerID[0]->city, 'balance' => $customerID[0]->opening_balance,
            'registration_date' => \Carbon\Carbon::parse($customerID[0]->registration_date)->format('d-m-Y'),
            'htmlCredit' => $htmlCredit);
        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Please can you try to uppercase all the `null as` so they become `NULL AS` in your code and see if the error is the same?

Comment: Not working still same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
$customers = Customer::where('id', $request->get('customer_id'))->get();
        $customerID = Customer::find($customers);

        $customer_credit_sales = DB::table("sale_invoice_masters")->select('sale_invoice_masters.id'
            , 'sale_invoice_masters.customer_id',
            DB::raw('NULL AS amount'),
//            DB::raw('NULL AS recovery_date'),
            'sale_invoice_masters.grand_total',
            'sale_invoice_masters.cash_amount',
            'sale_invoice_masters.credit_amount',
            'sale_invoice_masters.sale_date As Date' )
            ->where('customer_id', $request->get('customer_id'));

        $recoveries = DB::table("recoveries")->select('recoveries.id'
            , 'recoveries.customer_id'
            , 'recoveries.amount',
            DB::raw('NULL AS grand_total'),
            DB::raw('NULL AS cash_amount'),
            DB::raw('NULL AS credit_amount'),
            'recoveries.recovery_date As Date')
            ->where('customer_id', $request->get('customer_id'))
            ->union($customer_credit_sales)->orderBy('Date','Desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `selectRaw` for special column

```
$recoveries = Recovery::selectRaw('recoveries.id, recoveries.customer_id, recoveries.amount, recoveries.recovery_date, NULL AS grand_total, NULL AS cash_amount, NULL AS credit_amount, NULL AS sale_date')
        ->unionAll($customerCreditSales)->where('customer_id',$request->get('customer_id'))
        ->get();
```

or use `\DB::raw()`

```
$recoveries = Recovery::select(['recoveries.id'
            , 'recoveries.customer_id'
            , 'recoveries.amount',
        'recoveries.recovery_date',
        \DB::raw('NULL AS grand_total'),
        \DB::raw('NULL AS cash_amount'),
        \DB::raw('NULL AS credit_amount'),
        \DB::raw('NULL AS sale_date'),
        ])
        ->unionAll($customerCreditSales)->where('customer_id',$request->get('customer_id'))
        ->get();
```

same for `$customerCreditSales`

Comment: But it is not filtering data with customer_id.. I have used where clause maybe that is not working.

Comment: @DaniyalMughees instead of `->where('customer_id',$request->get('customer_id'))->get()` do `->where('customer_id',$request->get('customer_id'))->toSql()` te recover the built query and check where the error is